# How do I create classes in dart?

Tags: dart

I dont understand why im getting an error, can somebody please help. I just started to code in dart, but i cannot find a logical reason why this shouldnt work.

```
void main() {
  User userx = User('luigi', 21);

  print(userx.age);
  userx.login();

  User usery = User('mario', 33);
  print(usery.username);
  usery.login();
}

class User {
  String username;
  int age;

  User(String username, int age){
    this.username = username;
    this.age = age;
  }

  void login() {
    print('user logged in');
  }
}
```

Comment: I did it, i'm sooooo happy!!!

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

```dart
void main() {
  User userx = User('luigi', 21);

  print(userx.age);
  userx.login();

  User usery = User('mario', 33);
  print(usery.username);
  usery.login();
}

class User {
  String username;
  int age;

  User(this.username, this.age);

  void login() {
    print('user logged in');
  }
}
```

Your compiler should have underlined the problematic parts with a helpful error message. Best thing would be read the message and try to do what it suggests.

Maybe you should start at the beginning e.g. by looking at some documentation: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors

Comment: Thank u very much tmaihoff

Comment: sure. if my answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted answer, thanks